# Converting a line of code to a char string

Tags: lua

I recently wrote some code like this:

```
function enum(tbl)
    local length = #tbl
    for i = 1, length do
        local v = tbl[i]
        tbl[v] = i
    end

    return tbl
end
eItemType = enum
{
    "wpn",
    "outf",
    "helm",
    "art",
    "boost",
    "bkpk",
    "dev",
    "ammo",
    "none"
}
```

It works. But I would like to simplify it to this form:

```
enum eItemType
{
    "wpn",
    "outf",
    "helm",
    "art",
    "boost",
    "bkpk",
    "dev",
    "ammo",
    "none"
}
```

For the enum function to create a global variable eItemType in the file from which it is called.
I don't know how to implement this (convert eItemType to string in string code).
Functions from the debug library come to mind, namely getline, maybe it can handle it...

Comment: what exactly do you want to get , in your example , you supplement the table  `"wpn","outf", "helm" ...,` with values: `wpn=1, outf=2, helm=3 ... ` is that what you need?

Comment: @Mike V. Only partly. I want a global variable to be automatically created when the enum function is called, and this can be done. But here I don't understand how to convert STRICTED CODE (eItemType) to plain string, that's the problem.

Comment: as a result: the code needs to be converted into string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Enumerations in Lua

First of all: You're shoehorning a foreign language concept into Lua, which will necessarily not be round on the corners. Languages like C use numbers (integers) for enums because of their efficiency: Integer comparison is fast. In the end, enums are just synctactic sugar for enumerating integer constants though. **You don't need any of this in Lua**: Lua has **string interning**, which means **strings are only stored once in memory and can be compared as fast as numbers**. That is, the naive way to implement enums in Lua, is to simply use strings right away!

```lua
local enum_values = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
local function get_random_enum_value()
    return enum_values[math.random(#enum_values)]
end
if get_random_enum_value() == "foo" then
    print("Congratulations! The value is foo!")
end
```

The downside is that you now don't have any table holding your enum values, so you'll either want to brush up on your documentation or create a (redundant) hash table to hold your enum values (which really is just making things slower, but may help readability). **You don't need to involve any numbers.** If I inspect a table and see a `"foo_something"` string there, that's a lot more useful than `42`.

```lua
local my_enum = {foo = "foo", bar = "bar", baz = "baz"}
local enum_values = {my_enum.foo, my_enum.bar, my_enum.baz}
local function get_random_enum_value()
    return enum_values[math.random(#enum_values)]
end

-- May be considered more readable since we now have a scope for "foo"
if get_random_enum_value() == my_enum.foo then
    print("Congratulations! The value is foo!")
end
```

then you'd probably write yourself a simple helper to generate these kinds of tables:

```lua
function enum(namelist)
    local t = {}
    for _, v in pairs(namelist) do
        t[v] = v
    end
    return t
end

my_enum = enum{
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz",
}
```

### Syntactic Sugar

What you want is called *syntactic sugar* and yes, it requires Lua's metaprogramming capabilities. If you really want an `enum` keyword, you'll have to extend Lua or implement a preprocessor adding such a keyword.

First, let's see how Lua sees your current code:

```lua
someName = enum { ... }
```

parses as "call the variable called `enum` with the table `{ ... }` and assign the result to the variable called `someName`".

```lua
enum someName { ... }
```

does not parse: this is just a name, followed by... another name? Syntax error. By slightly abridging this syntax, it is however still possible to turn this into a valid expression. How about passing `someName` as a string to `enum`, which then returns a function to apply to your table?

```lua
enum "someName" { ... }
```

this would be implemented as

```lua
function enum(name)
    return function(t)
        _G[name] = original_enum(t)
    end
end
```

where `original_enum` is your original `enum` function without the added layer for syntactic sugar. You might want to swap out `_G` with `_ENV` or `getfenv(2)` or similar.

Or for another syntactic sugar, you could also use the indexing operator paired with the `__index` metamethod:

```lua
enum.someName { ... }
```

which is implemented as:

```lua
enum = setmetatable({} --[[proxy table]], {__index = function(_, name)
    return function(t)
        _G[name] = original_enum(t)
    end
})
```

both of these have in common that they are basically just fancy ways of currying the `name` of the global variable you want to assign to.

Answer (score 0):

f you need to get a table from a string, then try:

```
local s = [[ return {
    "wpn",
    "outf",
    "helm",
    "art",
    "boost",
    "bkpk",
    "dev",
    "ammo",
    "none"
}]]
eItemType = (loadstring or load)(s)()   --  since Lua 5.2 loadstring has been replaced by load

for k,v in pairs(eItemType) do
    print( k,v)
end
```

if you need a full copy of a simple table , then it is created like this:

```
enum = function(t) 
    local tmp = {}
    for _,v in ipairs(t) do tmp[#tmp+1]=v end
    return tmp 
end 
eItemType = enum {
    "wpn",
    "outf",
    "helm",
    "art",
    "boost",
    "bkpk",
    "dev",
    "ammo",
    "none"
}
```

if you need to move the creation of a global table or enumerations to another place, look at the solution through modules

and the last solution is to get a line of code from a simple table, used to write to a file and generate lua code

```
function dumpValue(obj)
      local s = '\n{ '
      for k,v in ipairs(obj) do
         s = s .. '\n['..k..'] = "' .. v .. '",'
      end
      return s .. '} '     
end

print(dumpValue(eItemType))
```

Comment: most likely, you need the last solution